# Getting Distinct Data from Every Column

Tags: sql

I have a table named article

```
Article_type   Article_Shade  Article_tool
A              Red            FF
A              Orange         KK
B              Red            FF
```

I want to get the distinct values of each column using a single SQL Query.

I have tried a lot of options please let me know if it is possible.

**Expected OutPut** should be:

- `A B` for `Article_type`
- `Red Orange` for `Article_Shade`
- `FF KK` for `Article_Tool`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What you are expecting is not combinable in one resultset. You can execute three queries: SELECT DISTINCT Article_type FROM ...; SELECT DISTINCT Article_Shade FROM ..., SELECT DISTINCT Article_tool FROM ...;

Comment: can you put your expected type in a table with three columns? Otherwise you are looking at three queries (one/column) to get just the distinct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done on Oracle, not sure what DB you are using, but hopefully this gives you an idea.

```
CREATE TABLE article (article_type VARCHAR2(100), article_shade VARCHAR2(50), article_tool VARCHAR2(75));


INSERT INTO article VALUES ('A','Red','FF');
INSERT INTO article VALUES ('A','Orange','KK');
INSERT INTO article VALUES ('B','Red','FF');

COMMIT;

SELECT column_name
     , val
 FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT 'article_type' column_name
                  , Article_type  val
               FROM  article
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT 'article_shade' column_name
                  , Article_Shade   val
               FROM  article
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT 'article_tool' column_name
                  , Article_tool   val
               FROM  article
) a
```

Output:

```
    COLUMN_NAME     VAL
1   article_type    B
2   article_type    A
3   article_shade   Orange
4   article_shade   Red
5   article_tool    FF
6   article_tool    KK
```

**Note:**
If you are trying to get this result back with 3 separate columns (e.g. one column for article_type, one for article_shade, and one for article_tool), that is nonsensical since each column could have different amounts of distinct values.

Comment: But in this..it is mandatory that all columns should have same data type. Am I right??

Comment: @SAM - No, the lengths can be different, see my edit, I adjusted the VARCHAR2 lengths of the columns and the query still works just fine.

Comment: @SAM - Also, for datatype differences (like if one column is a numeric type and one column is a character type) you could always use casts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is close to your expected output:

```
Aricle_type    Article_Shade  Article_tool
A              Orange         FF
B              Red            KK
```

While it is possible to create a query which will do this, it is seemingly nonsensical.  To sort each column of distinct values individually and display them together will show us records which may not exist.  You would be arbitrarily combining attributes that represent an entity that isn't really in the table.  In this case, there is a good reason that you haven't been able to find a SQL function that will do this.  The other commentors also bring up good points about why this is not possible, such as data types (you'd cast everything as a string, presumably), and possibly differing counts of values leading to nulls (which would make just as much sense as any other arbitrarily not-null row in this case).

Comment: @SAM, please let me know if my example output is not what you intend, and I can remove this answer.